When did Moira send the Lone Wanderer to bed without dinner?
In Fallout Shelter, according to a Raider in Formal Wear during the quest "Gameshow Gauntlet", Moira sent the Lone Wanderer to bed without dinner. When did that happen?

The Gameshow Gauntlet shows several possible answers with each question.
1 correct the others false, this is one of the false ones.
The false ones are often "funny" nonsense, like this one.

the question was which of these didn't Moria send the Wanderer and if you choose to bed without Dinner they'll say that she did indeed send him to bed without dinner.

Indeed, this one is considered wrong, while it should be right (the only right answer to where Moira didn't send the player according to the game is the Nuka Power Plant).
